# /etc/bind/rndc.key: permission denied

Tags: server, bind

[image: sudo rndc-confgen, rndc.conf]
[image: cat rndc.key, systemctl status bind9]
[image: cat named.conf]
[image: problem with rndc reload, rndc -V status]
[image: premissions in /etc/bind]

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=386791

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic
```

I have a problem with running `rndc reload`, I change permissions, add include, but I still have the same problem as in this link. And I need rndc for configuration according to the bind9 documentation.

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of text ... Copy and paste text instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated at the very bottom of your last link, you're supposed to do the following:

```bash
sudo chown root:bind /etc/bind/rndc.key
```

It's not supposed to be `bind:bind` like your last screenshot.